# How to add a menu item in admin console - [OPEN CART] [Best practice]

Tags: php, opencart

How should I be doing the following

```
- adding new form fields to the product edit page
- adding a new menu item to the admin console main menu
```

Are there any hooks that can be called from my extension? 
Or
Should I be editing the core files itself to add this functionality?

Comment: You may use `vqmod` instead of directly modifying the opencart core files.

Comment: Ah interesting ! Thanks. Looking at it.

Comment: +1 Sankar - vQmod is definitely the way to go for this - www.vqmod.com

Comment: Looked at it. Thanks. Will this process work well, if I have to edit quite of a code ?

Comment: yes it can be used to edit lot of code,there is no limit on that

Answer (score 0):

OpenCart is not a Wordpress and has no hooks You could use to Your purpose, nor it has no events nor event listeners that could be used as well.

When implementing some functionality for OpenCart for long time we only had the possibility to edit the core files directly which led to work lost when we updated to newer version, also installing plugins/extensions modifying core files was possible only in way *open file A, go to line XYZ and place this code there. Then go to file B ...*.

In past few years we have a possibility to use vQmod which was improved rapidly and using this You are possible to *inject* Your new code into existing core files and *remove* or *modify* some of the source code in the core files with the certainty Your changes are not lost after the update to a newer version. Of course, Your extension may stop working but it is a lot easier just to modify the changes in XML file then to re-implement all the lost work again (and again).

Similar to [vQmod](https://code.google.com/p/vqmod/) there is also some [Override Engine](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=8588) that should also help You to implement extensions apart from OC's core files but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looking at Override Engine as well.